# How can I give space between rows and corner radius of each row in table?

Tags: html, css

[image: need design line this in table]

I want to  design a page in like above image. I need to give space between rows and give border radius in each row. I tried in div tag. but I dont want in div I need **only in table** tag in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle

### http://jsfiddle.net/Lgp3m1ms/3/

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

th{    
background:#000;
color:#fff;
padding:4px;
border:1px solid #fff;
}


td div {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border:1px solid #000;    
}


td:first-child div {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
td:last-child div {
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give background and padding to the TR for spacing between rows use height and box shadow

OR

Give styling to TD only round the border at the first TD of the row and the last TD of the row

```
table tr td:first {
//style
}

table tr td:last {
//style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add different style to the first-child and last-child of the `td` elements in a row. So, try this:

```
td:first-child div {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
td:last-child div {
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgp3m1ms/)**

[Border-radius mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Note: In your case, defining styles directly on the td element is buggy. So, you should add a div inside it.